# why findElementsByXPath doesn't work for me

Tags: appium

I'm using appium to test android device

To run a click() action on a button, the following script worked:

> driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.Layout)[2]").click();

However, this format didn't trigger the proper action, may I know the difference?

> driver.findElementsByXPath("//android.Layout").get(2).click();

Comment: for the second script, i changed index number to 1 and it worked, but why...?driver.findElementsByXPath("//android.Layout").get(1).click();

Answer (score 0):

`findElementByXPath()` function returns a single element. And then you are specifying the xpath locator with index 2. Xpath index starts with 1

`findElementsByXPath()` function returns a list. And List index starts with 0. Therefore when you do `driver.findElementsByXPath("//android.Layout").get(1)` it returned the same element as `driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.Layout)[2]")`